# How can I run Neo4j with larger heap size, specify -server and correct GC strategy

Tags: neo4j, jvm, docker

As a someone who never really messed with the JVM much how can I ensure my Neo4j instances are running with all of the recommended JVM settings. E.g. Heap size, server mode, and -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

Should these be set inside a config file? Can I set the dynamically at runtime? Are they set at a system level? Can I have different settings when running two instances of neo4j on the same machine?

It is a bit fuzzy at what point all of these things get set.

I am running neo4j inside a docker container so that is something to consider as well.

Dockerfile as follows. I am starting neo4j with the console command

```
FROM        dockerfile/java:oracle-java8

# INSTALL OS DEPENDENCIES AND NEO4J

ADD /files/neo4j-enterprise-2.1.3-unix.tar.gz /opt/neo
RUN rm /opt/neo/neo4j-enterprise-2.1.3/conf/neo4j-server.properties
ADD /files/neo4j-server.properties /opt/neo/neo4j-enterprise-2.1.3/conf/neo4j-server.properties

#RUN mv -f /files/neo4j-server.properties /opt/neo/neo4j-enterprise-2.1.3/conf/neo4j-server.properties

EXPOSE 7474

CMD ["console"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/neo/neo4j-enterprise-2.1.3/bin/neo4j"]
```

Comment: You should show your Docker file and in particular how you start Neo4J. You need to pass the JVM settings to the Java launcher, how you do it will depend on your Docker / Neo4J setup. Are you using a wrapper script, then there is usually a variable you can set, eg JAVA_OPTS. If you call the java executable directly in your Dockerfile you would specify the options there. You need to give some more context in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you are using the Neo4j server script. In this case you should configure the low level JVM properties in `neo4j.properties` which should also live in the `conf` directory. Basically do the same thing for `neo4j.properties` as you already do for `neo4j-server.properties`. Create the properties file in your Docker context and configure the properties you want to add. Then in the `Dockerfile` use:

```
ADD /files/neo4j.properties /opt/neo/neo4j-enterprise-2.1.3/conf/neo4j.properties
```

The syntax in the properties files is the following (from the documetnation):

```
# initial heap size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=<value> 
# maximum heap size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=<value> 
# additional literal JVM parameter, where N is a number for each
wrapper.java.additional.N=<value>
```

See also http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-performance.html.

One way to test whether the settings are applied is to run `jinfo <pid>` in the Docker container, where  is the process id of the Neo4j JVM. To enter the container, you can either change the entrypoint to `/bin/bash` at the command line when you run the container or you use nsenter. The latter would be my choice.